# how to implement group by via distinct

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains two columns: `col1 | col2`. I want to select where `col2` is opposition empty and `col1` and only one row of duplicate rows

**My thable:**

```
// tablename [col1=integer | col2=varchar]
+-------+-------------+
| col1  |    col2     |
+-------+-------------+
|  1    |  anything1  |
|  2    |             |
|  3    |  anything3  |
|  3    |  anything3  |
|  4    |  anything4  |
|  5    |  anything5  |
|  5    |  anything5  |
|  6    |             |
|  7    |  anything7  |
+-------+-------------+
```

I want this **output:**

```
// newtablename
+-------+-------------+
| col1  |    col2     |
+-------+-------------+
|  1    |  anything1  |
|  3    |  anything3  |
|  4    |  anything4  |
|  5    |  anything5  |
|  7    |  anything7  |
+-------+-------------+
```

**My query:**

```
select * from tablename where col2 <>'' group by col1
```

Now I want to know, How can I implement above query via `distinct` *(instead of `group by`)* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
select distinct col1,col2 
from tablename 
where col2 <>'' 
order by col1
```

Comment: Is col2 nullable? Going from your original question

Comment: why you use `col2` in `distinct` ?

Comment: Can you show me it as subquery ? In fact I want to `select where col2 <> '' as t1` then `select from t1 where distinct col1`

Comment: The whole row must be distinct (no duplicates)

Comment: I can show u anything u want. Checkmark  this answer as closed done

Comment: Btw you complicate and make silly out of answer by involving subqueries

Comment: My example is different with reality a bit, In reality col2 is unique. then can you show me just distinct for col1 ??

Comment: Are either the int or varchar nullable?

Comment: `col2` is not never `NULL`. It is or full or empty ...!

Comment: select distinct col1 from tablename

Comment: In this case: `select distinct col1 from tablename`, my result is only `col1`, while I need `col1` and `col2`. For this reason, I told `subquery`.

Comment: Why do you think you need a subquery by the way

Comment: Go with my answer to your original question. Works whether or not col2 is unique

Comment: Distinct works across to entire column set (As a combination of them). You seem hung up on the fact it is in text closest to the word col1